# return an array of structs or an array of struct pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

If you need to return a `struct` from a function, you would normally return a pointer to the `struct` instead.

If you then want to return an array of structs, is it recommended to:

1. return an array of structures (pointer to the first element)
2. or return an array of struct pointers?

I have drawn a diagram for the two options below:

1:

[image]

2:

[image]

Given the following struct definition

```
struct values {
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

here is some sample code for accessing the fields of the structs from the two options:

Option #1:

```
 struct values *vals = get_values1();
 printf("%d, %d\n", values[0].a, values[1].b);
```

Option #2:

```
 struct values **vals = get_values2();
 printf("%d, %d\n", values[0]->a, values[1]->b);
```

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan what is best? Does it even matter which I choose?

Comment: The only issue I see to not use version 1, is that it might be easier to identify the number of structures in the second version, as a `NULL` pointer can be used as a stopper element, whereas in the first version it might not be possible to define this stopper value.

Comment: @alk, yeah you're right about that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only issue I see to not use version 1, is that it might be easier to identify the number of structures (returned) in the second version, as a `NULL` pointer can be used as a stopper element, whereas in the first version it might not be possible to define a stopper element.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you have a good reason to return a pointer to pointers (for example, if you want to modify the pointers themselves later on), I think a pointer to the struct is good enough. No need to trick around with double pointers.

Answer (score 1):

As an example for a beginners book on C, the question would clearly be satisfied better by option 1 (no indirection) as was pointed out by the answers so far.
If there is more to the question however (e.g. which is the best way to pass around structs in a large framework) then I would certainly go for option 2. Why? structs are complex units of data and tend to become standalone entities which are allocated and passed around and disposed in differing ways - all code that handles them by direct access will need a rewrite if data handling becomes more complex.

Answer (score 0):

For me, as the number of indirections grow, the code complexity grows even faster.  Thus I prefer your Option #1: `struct values *foo()`.

Should data requirements push toward #2: `struct values **foo()`, suggest creating a new type `typedef struct values *ValuesSet` and returning a pointer to that: `ValuesSet *foo()`.