# How to return an array of structs to Console Application from Class Library

Tags: c++, arrays, dll, structure

I have a Structure :-

**Test.h**

```
typedef struct employees
{
    char* name[5];
    int empi_id;
};
```

**Test.cpp**
I created a function where I need store the values within these structure.

```
int Disp()
{
    employees e[5];
    e[0].empi_id=10;
    e[1].empi_id=100;
    e[2].empi_id=500;
    e[3].empi_id=1000;
    e[4].empi_id=5000;
    return 0;
}
```

**TestDll.cpp** Console Application:

```
void main()
{
    LoadLibrary(("TestDll.dll"));

    int obj = Disp();
}
```

I need to return these array of  structure to my Console Application.I want to display the assigned values in my Console Application directly.How Should I return it?Can I send these array of structure as a function parameter then how should I do it.Since I need to send an array of 5.
Checking out the below link did gave me an idea of assigning the values to the structure but I cant display the values in my Console App.
[return an array of structs or an array of struct pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992525/return-an-array-of-structs-or-an-array-of-struct-pointers)

Comment: Anything to do with C++/CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change function signature in to

```
int Disp(employees *) ;
```

it' OK. What is not ok is how you link your DLL. You can either loat it at startup (it happens behind the scenes) or with LoadLibray, but this requires a GetProcAddress too. First way it's easier. It allows you to load a DLL as if it were a library.

Comment: @ marom : so if i use the structure as function parameter ,can i display all the values stored at different index ie for(int i =0;i<5;i++){ e[i].empi_id int::Parse(Console::ReadLine())} ?????

Comment: :I have a problem in accessing the name ?? @marom

Comment: accessing th variable "name" @marom

Comment: Well the dll must know the definition of struct employees. But declaration of name looks wrong, I would expect char name[], not char *name[] that declares an array of pointers to char.

Comment: I require five employees names ,Since char array stores single character I used them .I need to pass this structure to C# .If I just use  char name[] ,can I pass this structure to C#??? @marom

Comment: Further help can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028593/const-char-in-c